# Set up GDAL for C++ in RHEL

Tags: gdal, c++

I've got GDAL installed from the latest 1.11.2 source, but when I try to make by C++ executable I get undefined references to "GDALAllRegister" and basically all the GDAL functions I call.  The same cpp file compiles fine on my Mac, but I can't seem to get the include directories correct.

In my CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
find_package( GDAL )
include_directories( ${GDAL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

And I've made sure GDAL_INCLUDE_DIRS points to /usr/local/lib where the gdal libraries are located.

Comment: did you put the headers some where odd?

Comment: No, I followed the build instructions for linux on the GDAL website exactly.

Comment: I used ./configure --with-openjpeg=/usr/local

Comment: can you add the output of gdal-config to your question?

Comment: Joshua, see my reply on gdal-dev...

Comment: @kyle could you add your answer below so that others searching for answers will benefit from your work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested,

You need to set the include directory properly:

```
GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include

include_directories( ${GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR} )
```

on a normal from source build.  Some packages install the headers in ${PREFIX}/gdal (e.g. /usr/local/include/gdal), but the build from source does not.  Then you have to also link to the gdal library:

```
target_link_libraries( your_target ${GDAL_LIBRARY} )
```